# Since when "Gdol Hador" refers to a scholar as opposed to a Tzadik?

Tags: words, rabbis

Gemmorah [Psochim 49b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Pesachim.49b.2?lang=he&with=Rashi&lang2=he):

> "תנו רבנן לעולם ימכור אדם כל מה שיש לו וישא בת תלמיד חכם;
>   **לא מצא בת תלמיד חכם ישא בת גדולי הדור**,
>   לא מצא בת גדולי הדור ישא בת ראשי כנסיות וכו'"

Rashi:

> "גדולי הדור - **אנשי מעשה וצדיקים**:"

Clearly for the Gemmorah, גדולי הדור is a lower level of "piety" than תלמידי חכמים. Today we call the greatest scholars "Gdol Hador" as opposed to אנשי מעשה, so for us גדול הדור is the highest level of תלמיד חכם.

When did the definition change and why?

Comment: This question is nothing without its claim that "we call the greatest scholars 'Gdol Hador' as opposed to אנשי מעשה", so it would do well to support that claim with evidence.

Comment: תוספות ברכות לא: ד"ה מורה,  תרומת הדשן ב:רלז

Comment: @Alex In the Tosfos, "מורה הלכה בפני רבך את. ואף ע''פ שלא למד עדיין בפניו מ''מ גדול הדור היה ובא ללמוד לפניו: " how do you know גדול הדור does not refer to him as a Tzadik?

Comment: @AlBerko Is there a din of מורה הלכה בפני רבו for a tzadik?

Comment: @Alex I got your point but that does not really prove the differentiation between the two terms as the Gemmorah does it.

Comment: @AlBerko Doesn’t it prove that the term “gadol hador” was used as a description of being great in scholarship rather than in piety?

Comment: Names are not accurate symbols as in formal logic